# Where is self.value in this class?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm in chapter 8 in the Python Tutorial and there they are explain how to define your own exceptions, here looks like the `MyError` class inherits the `Exception` class, but when it override `__init__` the argument in the parameter value is assigned to `self.value`, but in this case where is `self.value`?

```
>>> class MyError(Exception):
...     def __init__(self, value):
...         self.value = value
...     def __str__(self):
...         return repr(self.value)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it says in the text [just after the example](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html#user-defined-exceptions):

> In this example, the default **init**() of Exception has been
>   overridden. The new behavior simply creates the value attribute.

So the class MyError has value, but the standard Exception class has no value. [har]